# Labview programming

Tags: networking, tcp, labview

Our project is LIDAR which is based on physics. The total equipment is connected to server which consists of various sensors. Server gives total information about the equipment like temperature, humidity etc. Server and laptop are connected through LAN. Our work is to develop a software using labview which interfaces the equipment with the laptop. To achieve that first we have to connect the server to the laptop. We have tried in so many ways using TCP/IP vi in labview. Both server and client programs are required to do this. In the server program we are using TCP Listen and in the client program we are using TCP open connection. Which IP address and port address should be given to TCP listen and TCP open coonection ?

Answer (score 2):

The IP address and port should refer to the server as shown in this snippet (replace port with your chosen port and localhost with your server address):

[image]

The example code I have shown above has two code blocks, the TCP Server should run on your server and the TCP Client should run on your laptop. The remote address would then need to be changed to the address of your server. Using the above example only shows how the connection is made and a single item of data transferred before closing the connection. You would need to wrap up some extra code to provide any handshaking between the server and laptop to provide the required functionality in your application.

In LabVIEW you will find some examples on how to use the TCP function, from the top menu select 'Help' and 'Find Examples...' then using the 'Search' tab type in TCP and you will see 'Simple TCP.lvproj' that should give you something that will get you going.

Comment: I would also check to make sure the port is open in the firewall's on both the server and the client.

Comment: Sir in the program for understanding purpose you have given "Hello"  string to "data in" terminal of TCP write vi in the server block. But actually in our application server is giving data and both server and laptop are connceted through LAN. In this case how can we give data from the server  to the "data in" terminal of TCP write vi.

Comment: I have added some description to the above example. You will need to run the listener on the server and wrap it up in a loop to handle sending actual data via the "data in" terminal of the TCPwrite.vi

Comment: we are using loop to handle sending actual data. You have said that server program need to be run on server. Actually Here server isn't a laptop. It's just a box which consists of sensors and various devices to monitor the LIDAR equipment. we can't run labview server program in it. And we can connect the server through LAN to our laptop which acts as a client.

Comment: OK, this assumes you are using LabVIEW on both the 'server' side and 'client' (or laptop). What device are you using to connect your sensors to the LAN?

Comment: If your server box connects directly to the LAN, you'll need to get hold of the documentation from whoever made it, to find out what protocols or ports it uses.

Answer (score 0):

If your project doesn't specifically require you to use the TCP listen/open VIs then you might want to consider some of the built in networking functionality that comes with LabVIEW.

I've had good luck with LabVIEW's network shared variables stuff where you can, among other things, connect a front panel control on the client to a variable shared by the server, and LabVIEW takes care of all of the TCP functions behind the scenes.

Here's one webpage about the feature:
http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361G-01/lvconcepts/ni_psp/